# Javascript Form Update Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, onclick

I am making an html form that will allow the user to submit numbers. Instead of having the user enter numbers, I simply want them to be able to click a button to increase or decrease the number in the text input. The following important pieces of code does this exactly how I want:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase (form) {
        var val = form.h1.value;
        val++;
        form.h1.value = val;
        }

    function decrease (form) {
        var val = form.h1.value;
        val--;
        form.h1.value = val;
        }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="textbox" name="h1" size="3">
<input type="button" onclick="increase(this.form)" value="+">
<input type="button" onclick="decrease(this.form)" value="-">
```

My problem is that I want to be able to use the 'increase' and 'decrease' functions for any of the other textboxes (such as h2, h3, etc.). I tried to change the code by adding a second parameter, id, and using it to determine which form element to update. It will not work though. Any help figuring out where I went wrong would be appreciated!

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase (form, id) {
        var val = form.id.value;
        val++;
        form.id.value = val;
        }

    function decrease (form, id) {
        var val = form.id.value;
        val--;
        form.id.value = val;
        }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="textbox" name="h1" size="3">
<input type="button" onclick="increase(this.form, h1)" value="+">
<input type="button" onclick="decrease(this.form, h1)" value="-">
```

Comment: h2, h3, etc. are not other textboxes so I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: You are doing increment and decrement on `string` variable, this is extremely fragile. Anyway, just use element reference instead, you do not need a form reference in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function increase (form, id) {
    var val = form[id].value;
    val++;
    form[id].value = val;
}
```

and

```
<input type="button" onclick="increase(this.form, 'h1')" value="+">
<input type="button" onclick="decrease(this.form, 'h1')" value="-">
```

A form works as a dictionary where you can address its fields by name. You do this by using square brackets. The name of the field is a string, so that's why you have to pass `'h1'` instead of of just `h1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes:

In your form pass a string of the ID instead of a variable.

```
<input type="textbox" name="h1" size="3">
<input type="button" onclick="increase(this.form, 'h1')" value="+">
<input type="button" onclick="decrease(this.form, 'h1')" value="-">
```

And in your JavaScript, change the way you are referencing the field int he form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase (form, id) {
        var val = form[id].value;
        val++;
        form.id.value = val;
     }

    function decrease (form, id) {
        var val = form[id].value;
        val--;
        form.id.value = val;
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing two parameters, you can directly pass the textbox element whose value needs to be changed. Try below changes.

```
<input type="textbox" name="h1" size="3">
<input type="button" onclick="increase(document.h1)" value="+">
<input type="button" onclick="decrease(document.h1)" value="-">
```

And your javascript functions will be like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function increase (element) {
    element.value = element.value++;
 }

function decrease (element) {
    element.value = element.value--;
}
</script>
```